# How can I edit an embed message multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I edit an embed message multiple times? So far, I have been able to edit an embed message once, but it won't do it again.

Here's the code:

```py
# IMPORTING

import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = ""
BOT_PREFIX = "!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
from discord import Embed

#commands
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
     

    first_embed = Embed(title='embed 1')
    second_embed = Embed(title='embed 2')
    third_embed = Embed(title='embed 3')
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=first_embed)

    msg = await msg.edit(embed=second_embed)

    await msg.edit(embed=third_embed)


#running the bot
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Results: (embed with the title, "embed 2") and an error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'

How can I make it edit the message as embed 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message.edit` doesn't return anything, you shouldn't assign `msg` again,

```py
first_embed = Embed(title='embed 1')
second_embed = Embed(title='embed 2')
third_embed = Embed(title='embed 3')

msg = await ctx.send(embed=first_embed)

await msg.edit(embed=second_embed)
await msg.edit(embed=third_embed)
```